# Critique My Question

Tags: discussion

[PSU Series and Parallel Tracking Mode, Current Limit Behavior](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478589/psu-series-and-parallel-tracking-mode-current-limit-behavior/478591)

I think this is a well considered and articulated question. Also not that deep or esoteric. So why hasn't it gotten any love?

Comment: Stop whining, look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1520178/what-does-dscp-mean-for-an-unmanaged-switch) masterpiece of a question! Sadly they have removed the _[tumbleweed](https://superuser.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed)_ badge.

Comment: lol. thanks for sharing your plight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it hasn't gotten attention because no-one who's seen it categorically knows the answer.  It's the sort of thing where if the docs are unclear or ambiguous, nothing short of a test to learn the real answer would do.

If you'd like some help designing the test that would tell you the answer, edit the question to so reflect, perhaps with your first stab at a test design -- though I suspect once you try your first stab, you'll have your answer.

Comment: that's fair, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes no one knows the answer to a good question.  Or rather, it takes a while for someone with the required knowledge to wander in and notice your question.

I got a "Tumbleweed" badge once on one of my questions.  Later, someone showed up, found my question, and gave me a good answer.  The "Tumbleweed" badge was given to questions that got **no** response for a full week.  No comments, no votes, no answers.  Just **nuthin'** for a whole week.

Sometimes, it just takes time.  It might help to open a bounty on it.

Alternatively, since you have access to the equipment, just try it out and see how it works.  You could then self answer.

Comment: yea, if closer I will determine it empirically